Red in Maple slab
I have several maple slabs that i am making tables from.  It has some very intense red flaming in areas that i want to remove.  I have tried 2 part bleaching with calcium hydroxide (draino) with 30 %hydrogen peroxide.  This makes the light part of the maple very white, but does not affect the red.  Any ideas?  Thanks. I added a pic below.  The person Im making this table for, does not want any red in it.


have any pictures?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This is very interesting as the first port of call for getting any wood uniform and v pale would be A+B bleach as you've used; I'm frankly amazed that it had no effect! However, the rule of thumb is that all reddish tones in wood are subject to natural dulling down/fading over time because none of the compounds responsible are light-stable. Those same compounds should have been bleached by A+B, but regardless you could try household bleach now (as long as the wood has been thoroughly rinsed!) to see if it has any effect. Could you try that and report [contd]

...back please? If there's no effect at all I'm thinking this could be mineral staining, but it's hard to make any judgements even with photos and essentially pure guesswork without them. At the end of the day you may simply have to abandon your original plans for these slabs and go in a different direction, e.g. staining dark, going all the way to black, or accepting the current colouration which has been turned up to 11 by the A+B staining — someone is sure to love that under a water-clear finish!

"It's not an imperfection...it's a feature!"

Thanks for the comments.  The only other way to reduce to red has been to put the slabs in sunlight.  I put painters tape on all the non-red areas, to avoid 'yellowing' of the light color.  However, in winter its a bit more of a challenge to get the UV rays.  If considered a UV light, but I dont feel confident to purchase the correct light.  Is there a way to post pics on this forum?  Thanks. Susan

It pains me you're trying to remove that. I think it's gorgeous!
